# pygame - treat a variable as a variable not string

Tags: pygame

I am trying to loop round all of the number keys on a keyboard (0-9) and thought to do this you would use this code:

```
for i in range (0,10):
    if keys[pygame.K_i]:
        pass
```

But obviously as expected, pygame.K_i treats 'i' as the keyboard input 'i' not the variable. I was wondering how to specify I would like to use the variable not the keyboard input.

Sorry if the title is misleading, thanks.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

The key constants (like `pygame.K_0`) are just integers that represent the keyboard keys. `pygame.K_0` is 48, `pygame.K_1` is 49 and so on. You can use the range `range(48, 58)`.

Comment: If i did this, how would I loop through the range?

Comment: Would I do pygame.K_.range(48,58)?

Comment: you'd do `keys[48 + i]`

Comment: Or just `for i in range(48, 58): if keys[i]:`

Comment: Thanks for the help ;)

Comment: You're welcome. It would still be nice to know *why* you need to do this.

Comment: there is way which I won't recommend but before knowing that these syntaxes represent integers, I used to use 'eval(pygame.K_keyOrNumber)'.. like 'eval( "pygame.K_" + str(1) )'. So you can try using keys[eval( "pygame.K_" + str(i) )]